# How to handle async errors correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

When making a GraphQL query, and the query fails, Apollo solves this by having a data-object and an error-object.

When an async error is happening, we get the same functionality with one data-object and one error-object. But, this time we get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` too, with information about: `DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`.

So, we obviously need to solve this, but we want our async-functions to cast errors all the way up to Apollo. Do we need to try...catch all functions and just pass our error further up the tree? Coming from C#, were an exception just goes all the way to the top if never caught, it sounds like a tedious job to tell Apollo GraphQL that one (or more) leaves failed to retrieve data from the database.

Is there a better way to solve this, or is there any way to tell javascript/node that an uncaught error should be passed further up the call tree, until it's caught?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you correctly chain your promises, you should never see this warning and all of your errors will be caught by GraphQL. Assume we have these two functions that return a Promise, the latter of which always rejects:

```
async function doSomething() {
  return
}

async function alwaysReject() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Oh no!'))
}
```

First, some correct examples:

```
someField: async () => {
  await alwaysReject()
  await doSomething()
},

// Or without async/await syntax
someField: () => {
  return alwaysReject()
    .then(() => {
      return doSomething()
    })
  // or...
  return alwaysReject().then(doSomething)
},
```

In all of these cases, you'll see the error inside the `errors` array and no warning in your console. We could reverse the order of the functions (calling `doSomething` first) and this would still be the case.

**Now, let's break our code:**

```
someField: async () => {
  alwaysReject()
  await doSomething()
},

someField: () => {
  alwaysReject() // <-- Note the missing return
    .then(() => {
      return doSomething()
    })
},
```

In these examples, we're firing off the function, but we're not awaiting the returned Promise. That means execution of our resolver continues. If the unawaited Promise resolves, there's nothing we can do with its result -- if it rejects, there's nothing we can do about the error (it's unhandled, as the warning indicates).

In general, you should always ensure your Promises are chained correctly as shown above. This is significantly easier to do with async/await syntax, since it's exceptionally easy to miss a `return` without it.

**What about side effects?**

There may be functions that return a Promise that you want to run, but don't want to pause your resolver's execution for. Whether the Promise resolves or returns is irrelevant to what your resolver returns, you just need it to run. In these cases, we just need a `catch` to handle the promise being rejected:

```
someField: async () => {
  alwaysReject()
    .catch((error) => {
      // Do something with the error
    })
  await doSomething()
},
```

Here, we call `alwaysReject` and execution continues onto `doSomething`. If `alwaysReject` eventually rejects, the error will be caught and no warning will be shown in the console.

**Note:** These "side effects" are not awaited, meaning GraphQL execution will continue and could very well finish while they are still running. There's no way to include errors from side effects inside your GraphQL response (i.e. the `errors` array), at best you can just log them. If you want a particular Promise's rejection reason to show up in the response, you need to await it inside your resolver instead of treating it like a side effect.

**A final word on try/catch and catch**

When dealing with Promises, we often see errors caught after our function call, for example:

```
try {
  await doSomething()
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}

return doSomething.catch((error) => {
  //handle error
})
```

This is important inside a synchronous context (for example, when building a REST api with express). Failing to catch rejected promises will result in the familiar `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. However, because GraphQL's execution layer effectively functions as one giant try/catch, it's not really necessary to catch your errors as long as your Promises are chained/awaited properly. This is true unless A) you're dealing with side effects as already illustrated, or B) you want to prevent the error from bubbling up:

```
try {
  // execution halts because we await
  await alwaysReject()
catch (error) {
  // error is caught, so execution will continue (unless I throw the error)
  // because the resolver itself doesn't reject, the error won't be bubbled up
}
await doSomething()
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! :) I was of the firm belief that you didn't need to get messy with promises anymore, if you used the async/await pattern all the way, but I guess async/await pattern still creates promises, and if they fail you need to handle the promise-exception? Or am I understanding your answer wrong? Maybe it's just a library I'm using that is using Promises and I need to chain the calls to that library, but after that I'm "free" to rely on async/await and not chain all the calls further down? Thank you once again! :)

Comment: Async/await is just syntactic sugar for Promises. An async function always returns a Promise. To summarize, in the context of GraphQL, if you're calling an async function (i.e. one that returns a Promise), you need to A) await it; B) chain it correctly by utilizing return/then correctly; or C) add `.catch()` to it to handle errors thrown.

Comment: If you're using async/await syntax, you are chaining your promises. Maybe that's the bit you're missing? Either way, these sort of questions are a bit easier to answer when they include actual code

Comment: Okey, I will provide code tomorrow and see if I can wrap my head around it easier! Need to see if I can find a template for sharing graphql-backend code easy.

Comment: Okay, so I found the issue, and it simply was that I didn't know enough of javascript. It had nothing to do with Apollo-graphql to do at all. I can't really accept that `workingRejection2` works where as `notWorkingRejection2` doesn't work, but I guess it has to do with me not getting promises 100% yet.
 https://codesandbox.io/s/m4q8jy6lvy